# 3D VRML viewer Fish-eye camera

Tags: 3d, fisheye, vrml

I'd like to view some 3D VRML objects in a VR world through a fish-eye (barrel distorted) camera view. Any suggestions on terms to search for, places to start reading? I've looked into Blender and OpenGL briefly. I need to be able to specify the fish-eye lens parameters and pan/zoom the camera through this world.

If anyone could point me into the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just google around: http://pixelsorcery.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/fisheye-vertex-shader/ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82/A-small-VRML-viewer-using-OpenGL-and-MFC

Comment: Thank you Archie! "vertex shader" was the keyword I needed to learn. I have a lot of reading to do on how things are actually rendered to screen. Much appreciated.